# Glassfish server settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, glassfish, jruby

We have a glassfish server and jruby application deployed, server side code always entertain the only single request.Is there any way where we can force it to process parallel threads.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on Rails version but you might want to try `warble`-ing with 

`config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 1
config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 1`